# Number of times a certain character appears in a string (assembly emu8086)

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

I have a random string, say 'coccoo' and I want to store in the AX register  the number of times the character 'c' appears (So in this case I should get 3, but I only get 2). This is my code:`

---

```
 include 'emu8086.inc'
 org 100h
LEA SI,x ; SI points to 1st character in string
MOV CX,n ; size of string
MOV AX,0 ;the initial value stored in AX is 0  

check:
  CMP [SI],99     ;ASCII for 'c', compares the content of SI with c
  JNE next        ; If it's not c, then move to the next element in the string
  INC AX          ;If it's 'c', then increment the value in AX

next:
ADD SI,2       ;go to the next element in string

loop check     ;do it again for the next element(CX is decremented anyhow)
ret
x db 'coccoo' 
n dw  6                                                         
END
```

Comment: the `x db 'coccoo'` line produces 6 bytes, starting at address `x`, ending at `x+5`, first byte beyond is at address `x+6`, but your loop will finish with `si = x + 12`. Make sure you understand the difference between "byte" and "word", memory is addressable by bytes (8 bits), so to skip over certain amount of bits you have to adjust address by value (amount_of_bits / 8).

Comment: You should only increment SI by one.

Comment: Thank you, @500-InternalServerError ! It worked by changing that line

Comment: @Ped7g I tried to make x a word, by changing the line `x db 'coccoo'` with `x dw 'coccoo' ` and still using ADD SI,2. It still provides me with the wrong result, why is this so? Since I'm working with 16 bits registers (AX, BX , etc), doesn't this mean that a 'word' is equivalent with 16 bits?

Comment: I'm not sure how line `x dw 'coccoo'` is compiled by emu8086, it's a bit ambiguous, as emu8086 does support only 8 bit ASCII encoding, so such line can produce either bytes 'c', 0, 'o', 0,... or something completely else, it depends on particular assembler how it will be compiled, and you can use listing file (with latest version of emu8086), or memory view in debugger, to see yourself, how the memory layout looks, which bytes are occupied by which value. This is actually essential debugging skill, to be able after `lea si,x` to point out memory window to `ds:si` address to see memory content.

Comment: Regarding 16 or 8 bits... yes, actually that's another thing which would make me frown upon reviewing your source. The `cmp [si],99` lacks data-width specifier and it's ambiguous under many assemblers. In emu8086 it will pick "byte" size by default, but in NASM it would emit at least warning, or maybe even error. `cmp byte ptr [si],99` is emu8086/MASM/TASM syntax to explicitly tell assembler what data size you want to use. Like that `cmp word ptr [si],99` is completely different instruction, comparing 16 bits (two bytes) of memory content. (BTW emu8086 syntax allows `cmp byte ptr [si],'c'`)

Comment: So, you are working with 16 bit registers, but what values you store in them? `si` is string address. In 16 bit x86 real mode the memory addresses are 20 bit, composed from two 16 bit register pairs, segment and offset, so the `[si]` memory operand is used by CPU as `physical_address = ds*16 + si` and the offset part is 16 bit, so your usage of `si` for that one is correct (also the way of using `lea si,[x]` is common way how to load offset value into register). Then you are using `cx` to down-count the loop, that's also valid, because `loop` does implicitly use `cx` in 16b real mode.

Comment: `mov cx,[n]` is again correct, because you define the memory content at address `n` by using `dw 6`, so there are two bytes forming 16 bit value "6" at that address. Having 16 bit counter of "c" occurrences in `ax` and initializing it by `mov ax,0` is again correct (although common idiom is `xor ax,ax` which is 1 byte shorter, but modifies flags), also the increment by `inc ax` is correctly adjusting 16 bit counter.

Comment: But your string is ASCII encoded, which means that every letter occupies exactly 8 bits (1 byte), so you need to advance the memory address (in `si`) only by one. The offset is still 16b value, so you must advance it by 16 bit arithmetic like `add si,1` or `inc si` (if it would be `bx`, I would be able to show you the wrong way to update it by `add bl,1`, that would affect only 8 bits of offset, which is wrong). But the value, which is being precessed AT that memory address is only 8 bit big, so to load the letter from memory you would have to do `mov bl,[si]`, not `mov bx,[si]`=loads 2 chars.

Comment: if you will try to do `x db 'c', 0, 'o', 0, 'c', 0, 'c', 0, 'o', 0, 'o', 0` in your original source, then your `add si,2` will work as expected, and you are effectively simulating `UCS-2` encoding, where every character occupies 16 bits. But then the correct compare should be `cmp word ptr [si],99`, to not count as 'c' some character with value for example 355 (0163h = the low 8 bits are 99, just like ASCII `'c'`, so comparing only 8 bits would make UCS-2 character 163h wrongly counted ... I'm not sure which character is encoded in UCS-2 as 163h, just imagine there is some).

Comment: @Ped7g OH MY, thanks a lot ! You explained the thing with the `phisical_address` more clearly than the textbook that I have! I'm new to assembly and all these concepts are a bit overwhelming, thank you for taking your time to shed some light on the matter !